# php foreach() displays error MVC architecture

Tags: php, model-view-controller, foreach

I have a problem detecting the error which I'm receiving. 
**Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

I'm trying to display an object's entities which are stored using Phpmyadmin. I'm using an **MVC** architecture.
**FormController:**

```
   public function run(){

        $tabteachers='';

        if(!empty($_SESSION['apply']) && !empty($_SESSION['application'])){

            $tabteachers = DB::getInstance()->select_teacher_id($_SESSION['login']);
        }
        require_once(VIEW_PATH.'formdeux.php'); 
    }
```

**Db.class function():**

```
public function select_teacher_id($login){
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM teachers,internships,students WHERE teachers.email_teacher = internships.email_responsible_internship AND students.registry_number_student = internships.registry_student_internship AND internships.registry_student_internship = '. $this->_db->quote ( $login );
        $result = $this->_db->query ( $query );
        if ($result->rowcount () != 0) {
            while ( $row = $result->fetch () ) {
                $teacher[]= new teacher ( $row->email_teacher,$row->firstname_teacher,$row->lastname_teacher,$row->responsible_internship_teacher,NULL);
            }
            return $teacher;
        }
    }
```

**Form View:**

```
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="20%" class="decoration">contact</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($tabteachers as $teacher) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>Lastname: <td>
                    <input type="text" name="lastnamepro" value="<?php echo $teacher->lastname_teacher() ?>" size="100px">
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Firstname: <td>
                    <input type="text" name="firstnamepro" value="<?php echo $teacher->firstname_teacher() ?>" size="100px">
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email address: <td>
                    <input type="text" name="emailpro" value="<?php echo $teacher->email_teacher() ?>" size="100px">
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Service: <td>
                    <input type="text" name="servicepro" value="null" size="100px">
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>mobile number: <td>
                    <input type="text" name="phonenumberpro" value="aucun numero" size="100px">
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
    </table>
```

thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: where are you sending the $tabteachers to view file ? what MVC are you using ?

Comment: What happens if `($result->rowcount () == 0)`? Then `$tabteachers='';` (a string) which will error if you try to iterate over it

Comment: Yes, I'm using it with a foreach loop to display its contents. @Poria

Comment: Undefined variable error @MarkBaker

Comment: My idea was to give $tabteacher a default value to avoid any potential errors @MarkBaker

Comment: Why on earth would you get an undefined variable error? You're defining it as a string before anything else in your `run()` method.

Comment: And then potentially you're trying to iterate over this strig as though it were an array.... if you have to default it, then `$tabteachers=[];` rather than `$tabteachers='';` so that you at least default it to an empty array

Comment: Nor is `$teacher` predefined as an array in `select_teacher_id()`, so what is `$teacher[]= new teacher ( .... );` going to do?